# c++ Convert 4bytes to UTC time

Tags: c++, date, time, utc

I want to know how to convert 4bytes value to UTC Time.
The language is C ++.

ex) Suppose 4 bytes of UTC is 0xACE62100 then corresponding split time would be 26th Jan 2000,17:09:00

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Comment: If i am counting correctly, hour, minute, sec, day and month alone take up a minimum of 26 bits. A `char[4]` has 32 bits. I wonder how you deal with 6 bits for a year.

Comment: Where does this value come from? How should it be interpreted? What does the documentation say? You need to cover these bases before you can start designing your solution.

Comment: @BIN Do you have one of these mystery timestamps that corresponds to a certain point in time later than 2006-01-01 ?

Answer (score 2):

Looking in detail, it would seem that this is a little-endian value; the byte string `ACE62100` interpreted in Intel order is `0021E6AC`, which [when converted to seconds](https://www.epochconverter.com) gives:

```
25 days, 17 hours, 9 minutes and 0 seconds.
```

Therefore, it would appear that your time is a little-endian number of seconds since midnight on January 1st 2000.

Comment: Why january 2nd? 25 days before the 26th would be the 1st, wouldn't it? BTW, it seems astronomers use an epoch starting 2000-01-01, but 12:00:00 UTC, not midnight.

Comment: It's been a long day... Let me fix that!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a diff timestamp sent in network byte order, so you need to convert it. On *nix (and perhaps others), there's `ntohl` for that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main() {
    std::time_t ts_raw = 0xACE62100;           // your input
    std::time_t ts_nh = ntohl(ts_raw);

    std::cout << asctime(gmtime(&ts_nh));      // your input converted

    // hardcoded 2000-01-01 00:00:00 UTC epoch
    std::time_t epoch_time = 0x386D4380;
    std::cout << asctime(gmtime(&epoch_time)); // 2000-01-01 00:00:00

    ts_nh += epoch_time;
    std::cout << asctime(gmtime(&ts_nh));      // your expected result
}
```

Output

```
Mon Jan 26 17:09:00 1970
Sat Jan  1 00:00:00 2000
Wed Jan 26 17:09:00 2000
```

Comment: However to get a correct solution we need to understand the timebase of the input. Does it include leap seconds? The OP's specification (or lack thereof!) _"4bytes value"_ is insufficient at present.

Comment: True. The diff wasn't big enough to figure out if a leap second was included in it to say for sure. If the diff had landed us in 2006, the leap second @ 2005-12-31 could have given some extra info.